# RADIUS and Active Directory

Tags: windows, wireless-access-point, windows-server-2012, ldap, radius

I have an ASUS RT-AC66U Wireless Access Point. It has the option for a RADIUS server. Does this work the same with Active Directory?

I have Windows Server 2012 R2 DC and it has the LDAP service installed as well. Is that the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

RADIUS and LDAP/AD are two different techniques.  RADIUS just defines a protocol for delivering and checking credentials, whereas LDAP/AD are directory services for storing arbitrary data in a tree-like structure.  LDAP/AD may be *used* as data-backend for RADIUS, but they might not be used interchangeably (you *might* authenticate »against« an LDAP/AD server, but you would have to »speak« RADIUS).

What you want is a RADIUS server that stores/retrieves credentials over LDAP/AD, but you'd still need a dedicated RADIUS implementation.  You could try to understand LDAP/AD as the message, but RADIUS as the messenger.

For more information see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RADIUS).